# How to mock task:executor in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mocking

```
@Component
public class SampleApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.Factory.getLogger();
    private KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = null;

    public SampleApplication() {}

    @Async(value = "audit-task-executor")
    public void sendMessageToExternalKafka(String casterMessage) throws IOException {}
}
```

In spring bean.xml

```
<task:executor id="audit-task-executor"
    pool-size="1"
    queue-capacity="1"
    rejection-policy="DISCARD_OLDEST"/>
```

I want to write a test to mock it, but not able to do it. Its throwing following exception.

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/SpringObjenesis
```

My test configuration:

```
  @Bean(name = "producerExt")
FactoryBean sampleApplication() {
    return new AbstractFactoryBean() {
        @Override
        public Class getObjectType() {
            return SampleApplication.class;
        }

        @Override
        protected SampleApplication createInstance() {
            return mock(SampleApplication.class);
        }
    };
}

@Bean(name = "audit-task-executor")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    return mock(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class);
}
```

Implemented FactoryBean to avoid invocation of @PostConstruct

Comment: Why are you mocking the taskExecutor ? Do you want to verify some methods call ? That isn't clear to me.

Comment: SampleApplication is being injected to another class ABC.java through @Autowired. I want to test ABC.java. So I want to mock SampleApplication as with SpringTest the executor is not getting instantiated.

Comment: You said it yourself: you want to mock SampleApplication.java, not the taskManager. Use @MockBean annotation on SampleApplication then. If you need more help, provide the test code please